# How to set a path for savefiledialog

Tags: .net, vb.net-2010

I want to set a path when saving. 
Here's my code. This code is supposed to set a path but it didn't work

```
SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
SaveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\Users\owner\Downloads"
```

Comment: Try it the other way round, as once you have shown the dialog I dont believe you can set the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set `InitialDirectory` **before** you're showing your dialog.

```
SaveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\Users\owner\Downloads"
SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare path before showing dialog

```
string path="C:\Users\owner\Downloads";
SaveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = path;
SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        dialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\"; //you should to set before showing dialog
        dialog.Title = "My Title";
        dialog.CheckFileExists = true;
        dialog.Filter = "Notepad (*.txt)|*.txt";
        dialog.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: the question has already been answered correctly. You add no new required information